# How to point session.add() to a specific table

Tags: postgresql, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

I am trying to iterate through a csv line by line and using the session.add function to insert the data into a specific postgres database and table.

```
import csv
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.engine.url import URL

# Define database
DATABASE = {
    'drivername': 'postgresql',
    'host': 'localhost',
    'port': '5432',
    'username': 'postgres',
    'password': 'password',
    'database': 'postgres'
    }

# Connect to the database
return engine = create_engine(URL(DATABASE))

# Sessionmaker returns a class
session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)()

# Open csv
r = csv.reader(open("E:\Testcsv.csv"))

# Skip headers
r.next()

end = False
while end == False:
    try:
        next = r.next()
            tableupdate = (
            var_oid = next[0],
            var_trip_id = next[1],
            var_route_id = next[2],
            var_vehicle_id = next[3],
            var_position_latitude = next[4],
            var_position_longitude = next[5],
            var_timestamp = next[6]
            )

    except StopIteration:
        end = True
```

How do I finish this code by using the session.add() function to add the data into an already defined table called "vehicle_positions".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sqlalchemy `session.add()` works for model instances ( [reference](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/session_api.html#session-utilites)), so if you are willing to use `session.add()` only you've to map your table with defined model ([sqlalchemy mapping table columns](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/mapping_columns.html)).

OR

If you are ok with using raw execute you can run the insert by simply using `session.execute('insert into table ......')` [reference to use session.ececute()](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.execute).